# How to search for <td>n in vim?

Tags: vim, search, vi

I can search for n with `/n/`

[image]

I can search for `<td>` with `/\<td\>/`

[image]

But how can I search for `<td>n` ?

When I try `/\<td\>n/` i get not found

[image]

I'm trying to target the `<td>name=`

Comment: Easy/lazy way is just search for `td.n`  The . matches any character to goes to next td<something>n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must search for `<td>n`.  The escaped version searches for a single isolated word `td` followed by `n`.

`\<word\>` pattern is useful for searching words even when they are separated by other stuff than whitespace or appear at the beginning or end of the line.

So try: `/<td>name=`